Behavior of subtree of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ under compactification of the latter to the riemann sphere
I consider a countable subtree $T$ of the integer lattice isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with directed edges. It shall be embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ where the edge $(u,v)$ points from $u$ to $v$ if and only if either $Re(u)<Re(v)$ or $Im(u)<Im(v)$. This makes $T$ a row finite countable directed graph without cycles and as such its $C^{\ast}$ algebra is an AF algebra.
I am wondering what happens under compactification of $\mathbb{C}$. This compactification is motivated by the deformation of areas of unit squares under meromorphic functions.
A) is there a canonical embedding of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ into the riemann sphere and
B) how can $\infty$ be adjoint to the lattice/subtree $T$? "Intuitively", it should have infinite degree but I do not managed to find an actual argument. On the other hand by the symmetry of the grid and my (basic) understanding of the riemann sphere, the point $\infty$ and $0$ should be equivalent by the inversion map $z\mapsto z^{-1}$.
C) how do you characterize the neighborhood of $\infty$ as vertex in $T$ or the "compactified lattice"?
I am interested in the structure of $C^{\ast}(T\cup\lbrace\infty\rbrace)$ but for this I first need an understanding of this compactification.
Clarification
Following the comment that the question is not clear, I try to explain it with the following diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T\text{ or }\mathbb{Z}^2 @>>> ???\\
@V\text{embedd}  V V @VV\text{embedd}V\\
\mathbb{C} @>>\text{compactify}> \hat{\mathbb{C}}
\end{CD}
I want to find an object which can take the place of ???, which I call the compactified lattice/tree, such that the diagram commutes. The idea is that said object should contain the point at infinity as well as capture the neighborhood relationships present in $T$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.
Basically, I want to extend an unbounded planar graph to $\infty$ by adding this additional point as is done for compactification or in projective geometry and I am looking for an appropriate notion to do so.

By pure randomness, trying to find better wordings for my question, I found that the term which I was looking for is "end space theory" for infinite graphs. And that in particular for directed graphs.
See for example under this arxiv link.
Apologies that I was not able to make myself clear in the question.

I cannot make any sense of this question, except the answer to A is obviously negative. Please provide details to clarify questions B and C.

Well, you can look at it as the lattice in the complex plane and a "infinite circle" around the origin, whose "intersections" with the grid form a set of infinities. Those are identified to get one point of the grid at infinity. This is heuristic, but this is what I need to understand via the question I asked.

This is even less clear.

You should read about 1-point compactification of topological spaces. In any case, this is not a research-level question.

What is supposed to be the relevance of AF Cstar-algebras?
